# How do I switch providers after waiting for 'x' amount of time when attempting to retrieve a location fix?

Tags: android, networking, gps, locationmanager, google-maps-android-api-2

I am building a GPS Android application whereby it retrieves the nearest places based on the user's current location. At first, I detect both GPS and network to see if they are enabled. If both are enabled I would use GPS first because it is the most accurate, and for my application it is safe to assume they are outside, therefore, retrieving GPS should not take too long. Nevertheless, there are always situations when GPS takes a long time. How do I therefore implement a way to switch over to NETWORK_PROVIDER if GPS takes over, for example, 2 minutes?

This is my code right now:

I check if GPS or internet is enabled.

```
if(!GPSEnabled && !networkEnabled)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error: This application requires a GPS or network connection",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
    if(GPSEnabled)
    {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
    else if(networkEnabled)
    {
        System.out.println("Getting updates from network provider");
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

This is the `onLocationChanged` method. I get the lat/lng values and then send them off to my server and then do appropriate stuff with it.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    //Get coordinates
    double lat = (location.getLatitude());
    double lng = (location.getLongitude());
    Log.d("MainActivity", "got location: " + lat + ": " + lng);
    //get nearest locations
    new GetLocations().execute(SharedVariables.root + SharedVariables.locationsController + SharedVariables.getNearestMethod + lat + "/" + lng); 

    // Zoom in, animating the camera after the markers have been placed
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 10));
    System.out.println("lat = " + lat + ", lng = " + lng);

     //Stop listening for updates. We only want to do this once. 
     locManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```

What would I need to add to switch over to Network or GPS if either one takes too long?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use both providers at the same time and determine more accurate location using, for example, isBetterLocation() function from this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html. In this case users won't have to wait 2 minutes to use your app, if GPS is slow. At first, you'll use network updates, and then, when GPS fixes are obtained, more accurate locations.

Comment: Thanks, I've taken a look at the link but I am having trouble in understanding how to use the isBetterLocation method. As you can see from my code, I am stopping the updates as soon as one single update is received. At least for my application, I don't see the need to continuously check for current location. What would be great though is to implement what you have suggested but then stop as soon as a fix is found

Comment: Sorry, I haven't noticed that you need only single update. To obtain current location you can use `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()`. If you're not satisfied by the accuracy or the result is null, you can also use `LocationManager.requestSingleUpdate()` (only for api > 9). As for the question: you can create a `Timer` and set it to execute a `TimerTask` after 2 minutes delay. In this task, check whether location has been sent to the server. If not, switch provider.